# Windows keys don't work (even on the virtual keyboard)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, virtual-keyboard

I have a Windows 10 tablet. My keys won't work on the virtual keyboard. They sometimes work after multiple restarts for a few minutes, but then they stop working.

Weird keys like ö work, though: if I long press the o, ö option comes up, which works.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you recently installed some software in your tablet?

Comment: I installed VLC media player a day back , but I used someone's pen-drive. I do have windows default antivirus, which never gave any alarms when I used this pen-drive.

Comment: System Restore is the best way to solve keyboard software problems. If your keyboard not working after you installed Unknown/known Software. So try this and if still doesn't work then will see in more details.

Comment: I do not have any previous system restore points

Comment: check out this link: https://www.wiknix.com/laptop-keyboard-not-working/  Hope this will work